# Reading next line of a file with fscanf()

Tags: c

I am using two functions to read doubles(read_double) and integers(read_integer) from a file.
The file format is as follows excluding the characters in the ( )'s

```
12345678   (ID)  
3.78       (GPA)   
3          (Year)   
20.5       (Age)
```

There are 5 of these entries in the file to be read.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double read_double(FILE *infile)
{
    double double1=0.0;
    fscanf(infile, "%lf",&double1);
    return double1;
}

int read_integer(FILE *infile)
{
    int int1=0;
    fscanf(infile, "%d",&int1);
    return int1;

}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *inp,*outp;
    double gpa1=0.0;
    int id1=0;
    inp=fopen("input.txt","r");
    outp=fopen("output.txt","w");
    id1=read_integer(inp);
    gpa1=read_double(inp);
    printf("%d, %.2lf",id1,gpa1);
    return 0;
}
```

When this code runs it prints the Student ID which is 12345678, it then prints 1.00. This is due to it reading first the ID again.

How would I make this read the second line and return the GPA (3.78)

I need to split the program so that `main` is in one file, and the other functions are on another.

Note: I will have to do this 5 times. Also we have not "learned while statements or "gets()" so please try not to use these or more complex methods.

Comment: The code works fine on my computer. I  I remove the unused variables (and remove the line opening `output.txt`, which isn't used anyway), it compiles without errors or warnings, even with `-Wall`, and prints 12345678 then prints 3.78. I am using gcc 4.9.1 on Linux.

Comment: @Jay Is this when you call to read_integer() and read_double() from a header file?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant... What header file? :-)  I compiled it, then put the values on a file called `input.txt` and ran it. The result is correct.

Comment: My class requires me to use a header file and two source files. So the prototypes for read_integer() and read_double() are located in my header.h file. These are then called to in main().

Comment: Oooh, I see. You want to split the code into "library" (the reading functions) and "main". That wasn't clear before. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, as this is what I think causes the problem because it makes the position of the read reset. (if that is how reading files works)

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. If you split the functions, then the "main" part of your program will assume all functions return int, and the double value will be read incorrectly. I'll post an answer.

Comment: If you want to read line by line, read each whole line with [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) then parse them individually, perhaps using [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, what you want is to split the program in library and main.
So, the library will have the two functions:

```
/* lib.c */
#include <stdio.h>

double read_double(FILE *infile)
{
    double double1=0.0;
    fscanf(infile, "%lf",&double1);
    return double1;
}

int read_integer(FILE *infile)
{
    int int1=0;
    fscanf(infile, "%d",&int1);
    return int1;

}
```

The *header file* will help programs that use your library know what to expect from the functions (what types should be used for their arguments and return values). It only contains *prototypes*, and not the actual function definitions:

```
/* lib.h */
#include <stdio.h>

double read_double(FILE *infile);
int read_integer(FILE *infile);
```

And main uses them:

```
/* main.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib.h"   /* <== here! use the prototypes so
                          the compiler will know that
                          read_double returns double! */

int main(void)
{
    FILE *inp;
    double gpa1=0.0;
    int id1=0;
    inp=fopen("input.txt","r");
    id1=read_integer(inp);
    gpa1=read_double(inp);
    printf("%d, %.2lf",id1,gpa1);
    return 0;
}
```

And compile them:

```
gcc lib.c main.c -o program
```

Now, the input file is:

```
12345678
3.78
3
20.5
```

And we run the program:

```
./program

12345678, 3.78
```

Now, *if* we remove the `#include "lib.h"` from main

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *inp;
    double gpa1=0.0;
    int id1=0;
    inp=fopen("input.txt","r");
    id1=read_integer(inp);
    gpa1=read_double(inp);
    printf("%d, %.2lf",id1,gpa1);
    return 0;
}
```

and compile it with optimization,

```
gcc -O3 lib.c main.c
```

Then the result is wrong:

```
./program

12345678, 1.0
```

because the compiler generated code assuming all functions return integers. And doubles and integers are represented in a totally different way, internally.

Comment: I am getting an error says that "Stack around variable int1 was corrupted" It then returns -1073741824, 3.78.

Comment: Do you get that error even *with* the `#include "lib.h"` line? What system and compiler do you use? And how do you compile?

Comment: Found it! Printed it as a longfloat instead of an int